# Where can I find a good google task api tutorial?

Tags: android, sdk, httpwebrequest, task

i am new on this issue so please let me down easy :)

I am trying to develop a android application and i am trying to work with Google Tasks Api.

When i created the project (in eclipse) i chose the Google Api, but im not sure if that means i have access to other libraries like Tasks or only android related classes. Just in case i downloaded the Tasks Api jar file ad import it into my project.

Now my issue is how to i make a http call to get back some json/data from this api, or any other google api, i believe they should be similar.

i believe the steps i need to take is:

```
1. import the Google Tasks Api into a java class
2. grab permissions from user to access the api
3. make a http request and get the data back
4. style the data
```

So, with these in mind i need a small crash course to at least point me in the right direction, because at the end of the day i need to know what i don't know to get more informed :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good tutorial - http://code.google.com/apis/tasks/articles/oauth-and-tasks-on-android.html

Here is some more example code - http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java?repo=samples